# How do I set up an UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer using Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I can't get `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` to work when I create when I add it to my view controller using Interface Builder, so I'm asking here to establish whether I'm doing something wrong or if there is a bug in Xcode.

Here are the steps to reproduce:

- Create a new Xcode project using the "Single View Application" template for iOS.
- Add a `UIView` to the main view controller by dragging one from the Object Library in Interface Builder
- Add a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` to the view by dragging one from the Object Library in Interface Builder
- Ensure that the gesture recogniser is enabled and that an edge is selected:

[image]

- Open the assistant editor for the `ViewController` class and ctrl-drag from the `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` to the `ViewController`'s implementation block to create a new `IBAction`
  ` Add a breakpoint in the action's method body to test if the edge pan gesture is being recognized

The resulting code is as follows:

[image: Code example]

If I run the application on my device (iPhone 6 running iOS 8.02) the breakpoint does not get hit when I do an edge swipe.

Is there something I'm missing?

**UPDATE: this was filed as a bug with Apple (rdar://18582306) on 08-Oct-2014 and still isn't resolved in Xcode 6.4 (6E35b)**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I set up a project to test your question and found the same issue you did. Here are the scenarios I set up to test:

- I did exactly as you did, using Interface Builder, to build the screen edge gesture. The only difference in my code is that I put a line of code in the selector so the debugger would have something to stop on. The debugger failed to halt exactly as you found.

  ```
  -(void)handlePan:(id)sender
  {
      NSString *test = @"";
  }
  ```
- I then created an additional gesture using the pinch gesture on the same view using Interface Builder and I was able to get the debugger to halt within that selector.  So Interface Builder seems to be able to build other gestures correctly.
- I then created the screen edge gesture manually using the following code and it worked as expected.

In the ViewController.h file I included the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
@end
```

In the ViewController.m file I implemented the gesture manually.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

-(void)handlePan:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                              action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [pan setEdges:UIRectEdgeLeft];
    [pan setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
}

-(void)handlePan:(id)sender
{
    NSString *test = @"";
}

@end
```

I ended up with the same conclusion you did - there seems to be something wrong with the Interface Builder's implementation of the UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer.

Comment: Wanted to add that I tested this in the simulator and on my device with the same results - no response to the gesture implemented by IB.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to test this. I have now filed a bug report with Apple: http://openradar.io/18582306

Comment: I've marked this as the accepted answer since it confirms I'm not doing anything incorrect, and that Xcode is not behaving as expected.

Comment: @zisoft I'm using 6.0.1 (6A317)

Comment: I can confirm this is still and issue with 6.1 (6A1046a)

Comment: Thanks - spent ages looking at this.  Still a problem with Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a).

Comment: No need to set delegate here.. is there?

Comment: Still a bug with Version 6.2 (6C131e). Not impressed.

Answer (score 9):

I have tried it in Xcode 7.0 Beta 4 (7A165t) and it's still a bug. Adding the Screen Edge Pan Gesture Recognizer via Interface Builder doesn't call the referenced IBAction, however adding it programmatically like this works fine:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let edgeGestureRecognizer = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "userSwipedFromEdge:")
        edgeGestureRecognizer.edges = UIRectEdge.Left
        edgeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(edgeGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func userSwipedFromEdge(sender: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.edges == UIRectEdge.Left {
            print("It works!")
        }
    }
}
```

**Hint:** Don't forget to add the *UIGestureRecognizerDelegate* protocol to your class. Otherwise you'll get an error at `edgeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self`

Answer (score 6):

It can be considered as a bug, but actually, here is something useful:

"After creating a screen edge pan gesture recognizer, assign an appropriate value to the edges property before attaching the gesture recognizer to your view."

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer_class/index.html

This requirement only apply to UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer, so I think that's why Xcode make it wrong, it must be implemented as the normal sequence, alloc->init->attach->set value. It will work to all other GestureRecongnizer but not UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer.

Comment: the line you quoted is referring to the edges value (top, left, right, bottom) which the author set already in the screenshot

Answer (score 5):

Xcode isn’t always a good neighbor. Sorry.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let panGesture = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panAction:")
    panGesture.edges = .Left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}


func panAction(sender: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = sender.translationInView(sender.view!)

    println("Trans:\(translation)")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that there is a bug in Xcode 6.4’s interface builder and Swift.  Also, Thomas LIU’s answer was also correct: it seems to be necessary to set the .edge property in code, rather than with Interface Builder.

Even though there are edge checkboxes in IB, they seem to be ignored.

I solved it this way:
Ctrl-drag from the gesture recognizer to the viewController class to create an IBOutlet:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var leftEdgeGestureRecognizer: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer!
```

then, in viewDidLoad:

```
leftEdgeGestureRecognizer.edges = .Left
```

and finally, ctrl-drag from the recognizer to create an IBAction

```
@IBAction func swipeFromLeft(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("===> Swipe from left edge.\n")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make sure that multiple gesture recognizers can work together you have to implement the method `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` and return true:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Sorry for the Swift code but you should get the idea.

This method must be implemented even if you are using a single gesture recognizer because the view can have its own (system) recognizers, such as `MKMapView`.

Comment: Unfortunately implementing the `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` delegate method and making the `ViewController` the `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`'s delegate doesn't make any difference. Still no edge pan detected. Regular `UIPanGestureRecognizer` works fine. Think I might raise a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Facing same issue from long. Its a xcode bug, its better to add it programmatically.