# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer does not react to view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view controller that have a label, and I want to perform panning to the right on that label.

So what I did so far is:

*add a pan gesture to the label in the nib file

[image]

*created a didPan method:

```
- (IBAction)didPan:(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *)sender;
```

and the implementation:

```
- (IBAction)didPan:(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    CGPoint newTranslation = [sender translationInView:self.homeLabel];
    self.homeLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(newTranslation.x, 0);

}
```

and changed the screen edge pan gesture recogniser to right.

I thought it should pan now but its now, what am I doing wrong?

tnx

[image]

Comment: Have you hooked up your gesture recogniser to the IBAction? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: @KristianFox yes i did..

Comment: If you add a breakpoint to -didPan does the method get called?

Comment: Nope :/ haa , why is that..?

Comment: Did you add the gesture to the UILabel or the UIViewController?

Comment: Yes, see in the image i shared

Comment: I don't think you've added the -didPan IBAction to the gesture recogniser.

Comment: How do i do that? And ill tell you if i did it :) sorry in newbie

Comment: Its difficult for me to explain it but its basic knowledge, you need to find tutorials to learn about IBActions & IBOutlets and then UigestureRecognizers with Storyboards. Good luck.

Comment: I use nibs, not storyboards

Comment: @KristianFox I did add it

Comment: Okay find a tutorial for using UIGesturesRecognizers with interface builder.  Then you will know the correct way to do it and you can see what step you missed. Possibly you've added the gesture to the label rather than the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

So I had some time to try it out myself.

Here's what the Interface Builder looks like with -didPan IBAction connected.

[image]

However that didn't work for me. I did some searching and found this also on StackOverflow.

[Possible bug with UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256985/how-do-i-set-up-an-uiscreenedgepangesturerecognizer-using-interface-builder)

So, I would suggest you try implementing it the old fashion way in code.

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *swipeFromLeft = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didPan:)];
    swipeFromLeft.edges = UIRectEdgeLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeFromLeft];

    UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *swipeFromRight = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didPan:)];
    swipeFromRight.edges = UIRectEdgeRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeFromRight];
}
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint at the beginning of -viewDidLoad and run the app. Does it stop at the breakpoint?

Comment: i added my connections screen shot in the end of my post

Comment: the problem is that I needed to use UIPanGestureRecognizer and not UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer